# How can I calculate length of subscription given a set of start and end times that may overlap?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a table of subscription start and end dates for a several customers for various products. I want to get one value for a customer's length of subscription with the company (regardless of product), but they can start and stop subscriptions for different products at different times, and I don't want to double count the time periods of overlapping product subscriptions. How can I calculate this?

A sample data frame:

```py
a = pd.DataFrame( {'index': {0: 9123, 1: 9919, 2: 191, 3: 8892, 4: 8528, 5: 8893, 6: 9124, 7: 192, 8: 8928, 9: 8602, 10: 9629}, 'user_id': {0: 163486, 1: 163486, 2: 163486, 3: 163486, 4: 163486, 5: 163486, 6: 163486, 7: 163486, 8: 545619, 9: 545619, 10: 545619}, 'prod_id': {0: 110, 1: 507, 2: 511, 3: 488, 4: 506, 5: 488, 6: 110, 7: 511, 8: 488, 9: 506, 10: 508}, 'created_at': {0: Timestamp('2016-08-13 11:38:21.706000'), 1: Timestamp('2016-08-13 11:38:21.712000'), 2: Timestamp('2016-08-13 11:38:21.719000'), 3: Timestamp('2016-08-21 15:29:02.863000'), 4: Timestamp('2016-08-21 15:29:02.877000'), 5: Timestamp('2017-01-25 00:26:24.096000'), 6: Timestamp('2017-01-25 00:27:00.205000'), 7: Timestamp('2017-01-25 00:27:00.212000'), 8: Timestamp('2016-08-10 13:55:15.608000'), 9: Timestamp('2016-08-10 13:55:15.623000'), 10: Timestamp('2016-08-10 13:55:15.636000')}, 'removed_at': {0: Timestamp('2017-01-25 00:27:00.220000'), 1: Timestamp('2017-01-25 00:27:00.231000'), 2: Timestamp('2017-01-25 00:27:00.240000'), 3: Timestamp('2017-01-25 00:26:24.108000'), 4: Timestamp('2017-01-25 00:26:24.123000'), 5: NaT, 6: NaT, 7: NaT, 8: Timestamp('2017-02-01 15:52:32.951000'), 9: Timestamp('2017-02-01 15:52:32.968000'), 10: Timestamp('2017-02-01 15:52:32.980000')}, 'length_of_sub': {0: Timedelta('164 days 12:48:38.514000'), 1: Timedelta('164 days 12:48:38.519000'), 2: Timedelta('164 days 12:48:38.521000'), 3: Timedelta('156 days 08:57:21.245000'), 4: Timedelta('156 days 08:57:21.246000'), 5: NaT, 6: NaT, 7: NaT, 8: Timedelta('175 days 01:57:17.343000'), 9: Timedelta('175 days 01:57:17.345000'), 10: Timedelta('175 days 01:57:17.344000')}} )
```

will yield this:

```py
    index  user_id              prod_id              created_at  \
0    9123   163486                  110 2016-08-13 11:38:21.706   
1    9919   163486                  507 2016-08-13 11:38:21.712   
2     191   163486                  511 2016-08-13 11:38:21.719   
3    8892   163486                  488 2016-08-21 15:29:02.863   
4    8528   163486                  506 2016-08-21 15:29:02.877   
5    8893   163486                  488 2017-01-25 00:26:24.096   
6    9124   163486                  110 2017-01-25 00:27:00.205   
7     192   163486                  511 2017-01-25 00:27:00.212   
8    8928   545619                  488 2016-08-10 13:55:15.608   
9    8602   545619                  506 2016-08-10 13:55:15.623   
10   9629   545619                  508 2016-08-10 13:55:15.636   

                removed_at            length_of_sub  
0  2017-01-25 00:27:00.220 164 days 12:48:38.514000  
1  2017-01-25 00:27:00.231 164 days 12:48:38.519000  
2  2017-01-25 00:27:00.240 164 days 12:48:38.521000  
3  2017-01-25 00:26:24.108 156 days 08:57:21.245000  
4  2017-01-25 00:26:24.123 156 days 08:57:21.246000  
5                      NaT                      NaT  
6                      NaT                      NaT  
7                      NaT                      NaT  
8  2017-02-01 15:52:32.951 175 days 01:57:17.343000  
9  2017-02-01 15:52:32.968 175 days 01:57:17.345000  
10 2017-02-01 15:52:32.980 175 days 01:57:17.344000
```

I expect the output to be a data frame with index of user_id and column length_of_sub that gets the value 175 days for user 545619 and 164 days for user 163486. I don't think it's a simple maximum though, since technically users could overlap product create/remove at dates. 
I also want to exclude periods where they aren't subscribed to anything at all.

Does anyone know how I can write a function that can be passed to .apply that will calculate the actual length_of sub for a given user?

Comment: What does the `NaT` represent?  Can I fill it in with the current date?

Comment: NaT means that they are currently still subscribed. Yes, it can be filled with the current date.

Answer (score 2):

The approach I took is to treat each `created_at` and `removed_at` as different events.  As I iterate through a sorted set of `created_at`/`removed_at` I accumulate in a variable named `has_sub` a `1` if the event is `created_at` and a `-1` if it is `removed_at`.  If this variable  is greater than `0` we have a subscription.

```
def count_sub_time(d):
    m = {'created_at': 1, 'removed_at': -1}
    d = d.rename(columns=m).stack().sort_values()

    has_sub = 0
    start_sub = pd.NaT
    count = pd.Timedelta(0)
    for (_, s), t in d.iteritems():
        if has_sub == 0 and s == 1:
            start_sub = t
        elif has_sub == 1 and s == -1:
            count += t - start_sub
        has_sub += s
    return count


b = a.set_index('user_id')[['created_at', 'removed_at']]
b.dropna().groupby(level=0).apply(count_sub_time)

user_id
163486   164 days 12:48:38.534000
545619   175 days 01:57:17.372000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I/You could probably sharpen this up a bit but the logic is there.

Comment: Good idea to use `stack()`. But, if `NaT` represents still subscribed, wouldn't the expected answer for user 163486 depend on "today's" date, instead of expecting 164 days?  As of today, it would be something like 1089 days.  I think that just requires replacing the `dropna()` with a `fillna(datetime.datetime.today()`

Comment: Yes. I’d use fillna. It seems that OPs expected result doesn’t match their description fully.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a couple of groupby statements (instead of "apply") to get the answer you requested:

```
start = a.groupby('user_id')['created_at'].min()
end = a.groupby('user_id')['removed_at'].max()
diff = (end - start).dt.days.rename('length_of_sub').to_frame()
```

```
print(diff)

         length_of_sub
user_id               
163486             164
545619             175
```

I'm assuming you don't care about periods where a given customer might have a gap where they stopped subscribing to anything at all in between other subscriptions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - I do want to exclude periods where they aren't subscribed to anything at all. Edited the question.